# When do extensions included as part of your app show inside an SFSafariViewController UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have two extensions included with my app bundle - an action extension and a share extension. Both of these look for either a URL or a web page as the activation key.

Inside of my app, when an `SFSafariViewController` is presented and the user presses the share button, **both** of my extensions show up in the share sheet regardless of whether or not the user has "installed" them outside of the app.

My question: What determines when/if extensions included with the app bundle show up in a `SFSafariViewController` share sheet displayed *inside of the main app*?

---

**A bit of background**

My thought was to subclass `UIActivity` and include the implementation of my extensions in the subclasses. Then, I would pass them to a SafariVC using the delegate method of `SFSafariViewController` so they would show up in the share sheet without the user even knowing they existed.

But, as my question states, my real extensions seem to show up anyways.